What is a good preconditioner for a block Toeplitz matrix whose blocks are not Toeplitz?
I have found useful references for finding preconditioners for Toeplitz matrices, and for block Toeplitz matrices whose blocks are themselves Toeplitz matrices.
But I have not been able to find a reference that discusses block Toeplitz whose blocks are not Toeplitz matrices. What would be a good preconditioner for such a matrix?
